# Why element.text() != element.@text?

Tags: testing, groovy, geb

I'm new to Geb. I was trying to get text of html element. `element.text()` sometimes returns correct value, sometimes empty one. `element.@text` returns expected value.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Can you give an example of when they differ?

Comment: I used `element.find` to select 2 links. I iterated over returned value and printed `it.text()` (correct/empty), `it.@text` (always correct), `it.html()` (always `[]`), `it.tag()` (always `a`).

Comment: And the two links are identical in their formatting?

Comment: I don't see any real difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

text() is for tag body and @text return the value of the text attribute

Answer (score 0):

`element.@text` directly accesses the text attribute whereas `text()` calls a function to access the text, probably doing some stuff other than getting the attribute.

**EDIT**

According to the [documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.6.2/api/geb-core/geb/navigator/Navigator.html#text%28%29), the `text()` method returns the text content for the `first` context element, which may be the reason why it sometimes doesn't return the value your are expecting (e.g. if you are looking for the text content for the second context element).

**EDIT 2**

For a NonEmptyNavigator, the implementation of the text() method looks like that:

```
@Override
String text() {
        firstElement().text
}
```

For an EmptyNavigator, null is returned

```
@Override
String text() { null }
```

**EDIT 3**

As both Navigator implementations don't have a text attribute, the `propertyMissing()` method is called.

For implementation details, see [here](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-core/src/main/groovy/geb/navigator/EmptyNavigator.groovy#L213) and [here](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-core/src/main/groovy/geb/navigator/NonEmptyNavigator.groovy#L468).

Comment: Can you explain what `text()` function may do? When should I use it?